# Angular js Stop working after few requests

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am using Angular with nodejs

i am sending get request to server on each window scroll

It is working fine for 5 requests, but after 5 requests it stops working.

I am using `$http.get('url')`

I am keeping url same for now.

How can I keep it working for more than 5 requests?

Comment: How can we possibly help you without seeing any code?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is node.js use "http agent" to create http connection.this connection implement socket connection pool,the default limit num is 5 per host+port,and http agent adds "Connection: Keep-Alive" param when invoke a request,then the returned connection can not be released,so  the following reqeust can do nothing but waiting.

there are three ways to settle this problem

1. forbid HTTP Agent,add agent: false when invoke get method. like

   var http = require('http');
   app.get('/status.taobao', function (req, res) {
   http.get({host: '127.1', port: 7001, agent: false, path: '/status.taobao'}, function (res) {
       res.send(res.statusCode);
   }).on('error', function (err) {
       logger.error(err);
       res.send(404);
   });
   });
2. set http global object attribute.

   http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 1000;
3. close connect automantically when reqeust returns

   http.get(options, function (res) {
   }).on("socket", function (socket) {
   socket.emit("agentRemove");
   I recommend the first one.